# How do I reprogram an immobilizer system on a 2005 Honda Civic?

Tags: honda, civic, immobilizer, reprogram

I'm currently working on an '05 Honda Civic. I replaced the steering column but now it has a different key. How do I reprogram the immobilizer system?

Comment: instead of reprogramming the immobilizer why don't you swap the ignition tumbler and other components if any.

Comment: Can't do that because the tumbler was already worn out.

Comment: The reason I changed the steering column was because the tumbler was worn out.

Comment: Okay I get it, cool

Comment: A locksmith may be able to service the tumbler. But you'll need to have the car towed to a dealer or a shop with the Honda HDS and have it reprogrammed. Also I'm pretty sure the tumbler comes out of the steering column so I'm curious as to why the whole thing was replaced.

Comment: If you just need to start the car to get it to a Honda dealer or other shop, you can always wrap the new key (just the plastic part) in aluminum foil, then hold the old key near the cylinder so the immobilizer system will see the old chip (the theft deterrent system doesn't know anything about the metal half of the key)

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the car towed to a dealer or a shop with the Honda HDS software. AFAIK There is no scantool-less method to do this.